# How to pause test execution in testng

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-automation-framework

I am using testNG, Rest-Assured and Java for API automation. Is there any way to pause the execution for a specific time if any event/exception occurred?

Comment: The same question is basically on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938538/how-can-i-make-a-junit-test-wait

Comment: "if any event exception occurred" the question here is different.

Comment: My answer to this would be influenced by what problem you're trying to solve using exception handling.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JoãoFarias how is that different? You just put an IF around it...

Comment: I quoted the difference in context: The Stackoverflows want to simply stop - this question wants to stop if a specific event happens. Similar, but different situations.

Comment: The purpose of it is: if we have a server slow down problem and it doesnt response within timeout period, then the test case will fail with 504 status code. And in case of server down (503), all the subsequent test cases also will fail. So, to avoid this kind of scenario, I would look for a solution, where my test execution will wait for some time before resuming again.

Answer (score 0):

[FDM](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/8869/fdm) is right. You can use the approach that is suggested in corresponding post on SO. So you can just use `Thread.sleep();`

Regarding sleeping on exception you can put your `Thread.sleep()` inside `catch` clause like:

```java
try{
    // my test code
}catch(Exception e){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw e;
}
```

Not to break the framework logic you need to throw the exception to the next handling layers so that TesnNG knows the test has failed.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner (therefore least error-prone) way of doing it is by using aspect-oriented programming - AspectJ for Java.

You would need to define an aspect with the following pointcut that catches after an specific exception is thrown in any method with the annotation `@Test`

```java
after() throwing(ExceptionYouWantToCatch e): execution(* (@Test *).*(..).main(*)) {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

This way, all tests are automatically fetched to this behavior - and you can change it but only updating this aspect.

See this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092503/how-to-intercept-method-which-handles-its-own-exceptions-using-aspectj) for catching exceptions.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175368/pointcut-for-annotated-methods-or-methods-in-annotated-classes) for catching Annotated methods.

Comment: I am not an expert in AspectJ so that I wonder if this approach would pause exactly that thread that is executing a test?

Comment: The aspect behavior is injected on the method - it's similar to Traits in PHP, the context is carried out together.

Comment: Thank you. Would give this a try definitely.